# Setup clang_complete in vim for gtk+-2.0

Tags: c, vim, autocomplete, gtk, clang-complete

I'm having some trouble setting up clang_complete to work with gtk+-2.0. For the standard library clang_complete works just great, but I'd like to use it with external libraries like gtk+.

In the directory, where I'm programming, I added a .clang_complete file with output from `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
-I/usr/local/include/gtk-2.0
-I/usr/local/include/gio-unix-2.0/
-I/usr/local/include/atk-1.0
...
```

`vimrc` looks like this:

```
" clang_autocomplete configuration
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType="context"
set completeopt=menuone,menu,longest
set pumheight=15

let g:clang_use_library=1
let g:clang_library_path="/usr/local/lib"
let g:clang_snippets=1
let g:clang_snippets_engine='ultisnips'
let g:clang_conceal_snippets=1
let g:clang_periodic_quickfix=1
let g:clang_hl_errors=1
let g:clang_complete_auto = 0
let g:clang_complete_copen=1
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: have you tried also adding the libraries (i.e. `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`)

Comment: yes, just tried it and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: hmm, are you on the same directory with the `.clang_complete` file? (you can check with `:pwd` in vim)

Comment: yes, that's ok. And a small program compiles using pkg-config and clang as well.

Comment: What is the output of `echo b:clang_user_options`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with clang and glib-2.0. Clang_complete could not locate glib.h so I added a .clang_complete file like this

```
`pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
```

It is located in the project base folder and I run vim from this folder.
It seems that clang_complete can now locate the header file but code completion for, e.g.,  glib methods still does not work.